# How to set space between listView Items in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I tried to use marginBottom on the listView to make space between listView Item, but still the items are attached together.

Is it even possible? If yes, is there a specific way to do it?

My code is below

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/alarm_occurences"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#EEEEFF"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/occurences"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My custom List item:

```
<com.android.alarm.listItems.AlarmListItem
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/alarm_item_background"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"    
>
<CheckedTextView     
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:padding="10dp"

/>

</com.android.alarm.listItems.AlarmListItem>
```

How can I make spacing between list items in this case?

Answer (score 866, accepted):

@Asahi pretty much hit the nail on the head, but I just wanted to add a bit of XML for anyone maybe floating in here later via google:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/MyListView"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
  android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>
```

For some reason, values such as "10", "10.0", and "10sp" all are rejected by Android for the `dividerHeight` value. It wants a floating point number and a unit, such as "10.0sp". As @Goofyahead notes, you can also use display-independent pixels for this value (ie, "10dp").

Comment: This doesn't help if you also want to show a divider without stretching it

Comment: FYI - can be done through code - getListView().setDividerHeight(10)

Comment: or android:divider="@null"

Comment: @Sojurn I'd have tried a 9-patch if I needed to some something like that.

Comment: @Sojurn check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27821602/1276636). It adds padding but doesn't stretch the divider.

Comment: Cannot see the divide line if use this approach.

Comment: You should almost certainly *not* be using sp as the height of a divider, unless you're showing text as part of the divider. 10dp (or a reference to a dimen) would be the correct value to use.

Answer (score 63):

Perhaps [`divider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider) or [`dividerHeight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:dividerHeight) property of the `ListView` can solve your problem.

Answer (score 45):

Although the solution by Nik Reiman DOES work, I found it not to be an optimal solution for what I wanted to do. Using the divider to set the margins had the problem that the divider will no longer be visible so you can not use it to show a clear boundary between your items. Also, it does not add more "clickable area" to each item thus if you want to make your items clickable and your items are thin, it will be very hard for anyone to click on an item as the height added by the divider is not part of an item.

Fortunately I found a better solution that allows you to both show dividers and allows you to adjust the height of each item using not margins but padding. Here is an example:

ListView

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

ListItem

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Indeed a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You should wrap your `ListView` item (say `your_listview_item`) in some other layout e.g `LinearLayout` and add margin to `your_listview_item`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <your_listview_item
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    ...
    ...
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This way you can also add space, if needed, on the right and left of the `ListView` item.

Comment: i wanted left/right margin so your answer was helpful for me but I don't like the idea of just wrapping another layout only for margin purpose

Comment: There are a few ways.. and that's the bad one in terms of layouting performance.. try to think at lists with tens (or hundreds) of items :)

Comment: @andrea.spot it wouldn't matter for lists with tens or hundreds of items unless that was how many items were visible on the screen at once. ListView uses view recycling (if you've implemented your adapter correctly).

Comment: This will not work if the ListView items will have a background

Answer (score 12):

My solution to add more space but keep the horizontal line was to add `divider.xml` in the `res/drawable` folder and define line shape inside:

**divider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@color/nice_blue" />

</shape>
```

then in my list I reference my divider as follows:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewScheduledReminders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/mediumMargin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="16.0dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/smallMargin" >

</ListView>
```

notice the `android:dividerHeight="16.0dp"` by increasing and decreasing this height I am basically adding more padding on top and bottom of the divider line.

I used this page for reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#stroke-element

Answer (score 10):

For my application, i have done this way

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/staff_jobassigned_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp">

</ListView>
```

just `set the divider to null` and providing height to the divider did for me.

**Example :**

```
android:divider="@null"
```

**or**

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

and this is **result**

[image]

Comment: I think, better is `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to show a divider with margins and without stretching it - use InsetDrawable (size must be in a format, about which said @Nik Reiman):

ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@drawable/separator_line"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0px"/>
```

@drawable/separator_line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="5.0px"
    android:insetRight="5.0px"
    android:insetTop="8.0px"
    android:insetBottom="8.0px">

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/colorStart"
            android:centerColor="@color/colorCenter"
            android:endColor="@color/colorEnd"
            android:type="linear"
            android:angle="0">
        </gradient>
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="3dp"
```

example:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:divider="@null" android:clickable="false"/>
```

Comment: Combining null with [list item layout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16824435/5437165) produces the best effect

Answer (score 5):

I realize that an answer was already been selected, but I just wanted to share what ended up working for me when I ran into this issue.

I had a listView where each entry in the listView was defined by its own layout, similar to what Sammy posted in his question. I tried the suggested approach of changing the divider height, but that did not end up looking all too pretty, even with an invisible divider. After some experimentation, I simply added an `android:paddingBottom="5dip"` to the last TextView layout element in the XML file that defines individual listView entries.

This ended up giving me exactly what I was trying to achieve via the use of `android:layout_marginBottom`. I found this solution to produce a more aesthetically pleasing result than trying to increase the divider height.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of giving margin, you should give padding:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:divider="@android:color/green"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="5dp" >

</ListView>
```

OR

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/green"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp" >

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution with OP's existing code (list items already have got padding) is to add following code:

```
listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));  //hide the divider
listView.setClipToPadding(false);   // list items won't clip, so padding stays
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459179/1276636) SO answer helped me.

**Note:** You may face a bug of the list item recycling too soon on older platforms, as has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15915226/1276636).

Comment: you can set divider to null and set dividerHeight to whatever you like.

Comment: @Andy I think it will also remove the padding between items. Which will be creating the issue which the OP wanted to solve..

Answer (score 2):

you just need to make background transparent of list divider  and make height according to your needed gap.

```
<ListView 
         android:id="@+id/custom_list"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:divider="#00ffffff"
         android:dividerHeight="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

and set `paddingTop`, `paddingBottom` and `dividerHeight` to the same value to get equal spacing between all elements and space at the top and bottom of the list.

I set `clipToPadding` to `false` to let the views be drawn in this padded area.

I set `divider` to `@null` to remove the lines between list elements.

Answer (score 1):

Also one more way to increase the spacing between the list items is that you add an empty view to your adapter code by providing the layout_height attribute with the spacing you require. For e.g. in order to increase the bottom spacing between your list items add this dummy view(empty view) to the end of your list items.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"/>
```

So this will provide a bottom spacing of 15 dp between list view items. You can directly add this if the parent layout is LinearLayout and orientation is vertical or take appropriate steps for other layout. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will help you add the divider height.

```
 getListView().setDividerHeight(10)
```

If you want to add a custom view, you can add a small view in the listView item layout itself.

Answer (score 0):

In order to give spacing between views inside a listView please use padding on your inflate views.

You can use `android:paddingBottom="(number)dp"` && `android:paddingTop="(number)dp"` on your view or views you're inflate inside your listview.

The divider solution is just a fix, because some day, when you'll want to use a divider color (right now it's transparent) you will see that the divider line is been stretched.

Answer (score 0):

I found a not-so-good solution for this in case you are using a HorizontalListView, since dividers don't seem to work with it, but I think it'll work either way for the more common ListView.

Just adding:

```
<View
android:layout_marginBottom="xx dp/sp"/>
```

in the bottomest View of the Layout you inflate in the adapter class will create spacing between items

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these solutions work. However, if all you want is to be able to set the margin between items the simplest method I have come up with is to wrap your item - in your case the CheckedTextView - in a LinearLayout and put your margin formatting for the item in that, not the root-layout. Be sure to give this wrapping layout an id and create it along with your CheckedTextView in your adapter.

That's it. In effect, you are instantiating the margin at the item level for the ListView. Because the ListView does not know about any item layout - only your adapter does. This basically inflates the part of the item layout that was being ignored before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add android:layout_marginTop = "15dp" and android:layout_marginBottom = "15dp" in the outermost Layout