# Android ListView padding for content without moving ListView height?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView with a bunch of items inside it. How do I make the top and bottom items have a top margin of 10dp for top item and bottom margin of 10dp for bottom item? Now I can do this with padding or margin on the ListView but the result is that when you scroll the edge of the ListView is now 10dp from the bottom of the screen. Anyway around this? I have also tried setting margins inside of the getView method of my adapter but I don't see any margin options for AbsListView.LayoutParams. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Nasty suggestion, but how about a top / bottom padding for the first / last item view? You would have to check and set it on all views in `getView`...

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The trick is to include `android:clipToPadding="false"` in your view definition, e.g.:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="16dip"
    android:paddingBottom="16dip"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and was a simple solution. This worked fine and I am building against Android 2.1-update1.

Comment: Why only in Android 3.0+? According to the Android Reference this features has been there since the very beginning (API Level 1): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setClipToPadding(boolean)

Comment: lol spent 45 minutes trying to get this to work with all sorts of padding and margin setup.  Even came accross clipToPadding but misunderstood it and set it to true :)  Thanks

Comment: finally a working solution after wasting 2-3 hours figuring out what the padding is working weird ;_;

Answer (score 12):

You can get space at the top and bottom of your ListView, inside the scrolling region, by using headers and footers. Here's a quick example:

Define your filler view, which I named header_footer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"/>
```

Now your `onCreate` method looks like this, assuming you named your ListView `listView`:

```
    final LayoutInflater inflater = 
        (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View headerFooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_footer, null);
    listView.addFooterView(headerFooter);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerFooter);
```

And then set your adapter.

Comment: Works great, I believe in all android version, whereas using clipToPadding (solution above) only works on certain androd versions

Comment: Useful answer, thanks! I've edited it just to remove the unnecessary complexity. A simple `View` will do fine - there's no need for a `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just check the position of the item relative to the size of your list:

Padding:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
         //recycle views and whatever else you normally would do goes here..
         //...
         //...

         if (position == 0){
            convertView.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0); //padding on top for top item
         }
         else if (position == getCount() - 1){
            convertView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10); //padding on bottom for bottom item
         }
         else{
            convertView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); //no padding
         }
}
```

For margins use

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Ex:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
             //recycle views and whatever else you normally would do goes here..
             //...
             //...
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             if (position == 0){
                 lp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0); //margin on top for top item
             }
             else if (position == getCount() - 1){
                lp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10); //margin on bottom for bottom item
             }
             else{
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); //no margin
             }
             convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

this is provided you've implemented the getCount() method properly for your adapter.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Using the G+ type of header (that goes up on scrolling down and down on scrolling up) makes it impossible to have a headerview and to have paddings to the listview itself.