# Adding bottom margin to ListView last element

Tags: android, centering, android-drawable

I need to add to add ListView with complicated items background: different for even/odd and rounded corners at the top and bottom. It looks like this:

[image: ListView top]

I have implemented all this stuff via level-list, but there is one more thing I want to do.
Now the bottom item is near the bottom of the screen. It is better to add some space.

[image: ListView bottom looks not good]

I don't want to add bottom margin to ListView, I need margin only for last item.

The ways I see to do this:

### Footer

A kind of hack – add footer with empty TextView to ListView. But footers are quite unstable things, they usually disappear after notifyDataSetChanged and there is no way to get them back

### Image with transparent pixels

I asked designer to add transparent pixels to bottom background resource. Unfortunately, in this case vertical centering is completely broken.
For example, there is 9patch like this:

[image: 9patch]

And layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <!-- View with background with transparent pixels on bottom -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/item"
                  android:background="@drawable/some_bgr"
                  android:padding="10dp"
            >
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:text="Title"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="18sp"
                />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Detail"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="18sp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Just for marking place took by view -->
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_below="@id/item"
                 android:background="#88ff55"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result:

[image: Result]

As you see, centering is not working. Unfortunately.
(BTW, if specify this 9patch as background for TextView, centering works good. If you know any article, explaining this, please let me know.)

### Add bottom margin to last item in Adapter implementation

That should work, but for unknown reason I still can't get it work. 
I don't like this way, because I don't like to modify dimensions in code.

### So

There is already imaginary way – construct some XML drawable with particular bitmap and margin. According to drawables concept it should be possible, but I can't find implementation. May be somebody knows?

Any other ideas?

Comment: you just want to add a margin after the last item?

Comment: Yes. The question sounds exactly like this

Comment: I would actually consider using the footer approach. I've never seen them disappear by themselves, especially not after a call to `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You may be doing something else wrong if that's happening. A footer is managed by the `ListView` and has little to do with an adapter's actual dataset.

Comment: Best way is 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288167/add-margin-above-top-listview-item-and-below-last-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288167/add-margin-above-top-listview-item-and-below-last-in-android
it really helped me

Comment: Can you please update the accepted answer here? Thanks

Answer (score 296, accepted):

In your `ListView`, set a `paddingBottom` and `clipToPadding="false"`.

```
  <ListView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="8dp"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
```

- This also works for `RecyclerView`.
- Only use `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` if you want the scroll bar to not overflow into the padded area.

Comment: my 8dp from bottom is clipped...actually i want 8dp bottom only for last item..so what to do?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner I don't understand what you want. That is exactly what this does.

Comment: Don't forget to add `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` so your scrollbar doesn't stay inside the padding

Comment: there may be some trouble with colors. Bottom padding has the background color of listview, not the background color of the last item

Comment: Can we manage SwipeRefreshLayout refresh indicator using this?

Answer (score 8):

add an empty footer in your list like this:

```
TextView empty = new TextView(this);
empty.setHeight(150);
listview.addFooterView(empty);
```

Comment: for that I recommend: listview.addFooterView(empty, data: null, isSelectable: false);

Answer (score 4):

you can also do it from code if you want, for example here I react to
to EditText different situations:

```
   if(s.toString().length()>0)
   {
      contacts_lv.setClipToPadding(false);
      contacts_lv.setPadding(0,0,0,270*screenDensity);
   }
   else
   {
      contacts_lv.setClipToPadding(true);
      contacts_lv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Clocksmith's answer is the best and pretty clever. You can also create an empty footer view.

Comment: the first solution didn't work, but your suggestion did, indeed good idea thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines in your listView XML code:

```
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"  
android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be that you make a mock view with certain height.

In your adapter in getViewCount return 2.

In getCount return yourData.size+1.

In getViewType check if the element is last element return 2;

Use this type in getView to populate the mockview.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you want to add margin only to last item:

So you can do in this manner, in your getview method the index of the list item and check if its the last item, then progrmatically add margin to the view.

Comment: I've described this way in "Add bottom margin to last item in Adapter implementation". I wonder if there are more elegant ways.

Comment: Why do you dont want to do in this way?

Comment: Please see explanation in question.

Comment: No other ideas – so seems to be the only way

Comment: @Goofy How do you add the margin to the last row view of the list ?