# Android: Why there are a blank space at the bottom of RecyclerView which is inside of NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

Using an `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` is creating a strange blank space (like bottom padding) in the `activity`, causing unnecessary scroll, because there aren't more elements to show.

This padding grows with the `RecyclerView`, I mean:

If in the `RecyclerView` there are 0 to 2 elements, this fit perfect on the screen, and there are no scroll. Here works well.

If in the `RecyclerView` there are 3 to 5 elements, these elements continue to fit on the screen BUT in this case there are more blank space that causing the unnecessary scroll.

With more elements, the blank space continue growing and creating more and more scroll.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ibosca.thub.ChannelProfileActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/channelPicture"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/channelName"
            android:layout_width="256dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/channelPicture"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/channelPicture"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentsText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/contents"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contentsText" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/contentList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line2"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What it's causing this space?
How can I remove it?

**EDIT: ISSUE**

Here you can see the error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nSc4l2c2jg

**EDIT 2: RECYCLER**

Adapter:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.ibosca.thub.R;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.Channel;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.Content;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.ContentList;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ContentList contentList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public CircleImageView picture;
    public TextView channel;
    public TextView lastEdit;
    public ImageView badge;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        picture  = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        channel  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.channel);
        lastEdit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastEdit);
        badge    = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    }
}


public ContentAdapter(ContentList contentList) {
    this.contentList = contentList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.content_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Get Content
    Content content = contentList.getContents().get(position);

    //Set title
    holder.title.setText(content.getTitle());

    //Set last edit, channel and picture
    holder.lastEdit.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(content.getLastEdit()));
    Channel channel = contentList.findChannelById(content.getChannelId());
    String channelPicture = channel.getPicture();

    holder.channel.setText(channel.getName());
    Picasso.with(holder.picture.getContext()).load(channelPicture).into(holder.picture);

    holder.badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(content.isRead()){
        holder.badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contentList.getContents().size();
}


}
```

Recycler View (each row):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_weight=".90"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/picture"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picture"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/picture"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/channel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_weight=".90"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/picture"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picture"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.51" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastEdit"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="notificationBadge"
    android:src="@drawable/orange_badge"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: share screenshot

Comment: @Omi I added a video showing the issue. See last edit. Than you!

Comment: share code related recycler..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36101021/8122500 just adding paddingBottom with clipToPadding="false" for make a gap on last item on recyclerView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you xml file, change:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

to

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">
```

Or

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: I have the same problem. this solution doesn't work.

Comment: How you fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a linear layout in a NestedScrollView.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bck_primary_gradient"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  

      <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_15">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                      />
            </LinearLayout>
    
    
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling `setHasFixedSize(false)` on the recyclerview