# How to support full screen navigation UI for RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

### Background

I wanted to support full screen navigation UI as shown here:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windowinsets-listeners-to-layouts-8f9ccc8fa4d1
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/gesturenav

### The problem

While all Activities of my app worked fine, I suddently reached a problematic one that has a RecyclerView with thumbs.

Here, I got 2 weird issues:

1. When scrolling to the bottom, the last item/s don't get fully shown.

[image]

2. When in landscape mode, the thumbs go outside of anywhere that I can reach, so they are also not touchable. Not only that, but I can also see the normal scrollbar, and both get to disappear when scrolling to the bottom:

[image]

### What I've tried

I tried to apply the insets to various views, including both padding and margins, but nothing helped.

Also, in some websites I saw that I should use `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` and in some that I need to also add `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`. Didn't help.

Here's my current code (project available [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143530492), as I think this is a bug) :

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {
    inline fun View.updateMargins(@Px left: Int = marginLeft, @Px top: Int = marginTop, @Px right: Int = marginRight, @Px bottom: Int = marginBottom) {
        updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            this.bottomMargin = bottom
            this.topMargin = top
            this.leftMargin = left
            this.rightMargin = right
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).systemUiVisibility =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(appBarLayout) { _, insets ->
            val systemWindowInsets = insets.systemWindowInsets
            appBarLayout.updateMargins(
                left = systemWindowInsets.left,
                top = systemWindowInsets.top,
                right = systemWindowInsets.right
            )
            insets
        }

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(recyclerView) { _, insets ->
            val systemWindowInsets = insets.systemWindowInsets
            recyclerView.updatePadding(
                left = systemWindowInsets.left,
                bottom = systemWindowInsets.bottom,
                right = systemWindowInsets.right
            )
            insets
        }

        recyclerView.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
            init {
                setHasStableIds(true)
            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(
                parent: ViewGroup,
                viewType: Int
            ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
                    LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
                ) {}
            }

            override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

            override fun getItemCount(): Int = 100

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                holder.itemView.imageView.setColorFilter(if (position % 2 == 0) 0xffff0000.toInt() else 0xff00ff00.toInt())
                holder.itemView.textView.text = "item $position"
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menu.add("test").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            true
        }.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

**styles.xml** (I use AppTheme in the manifest as theme)

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
            @android:color/transparent
        </item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimaryDark
        </item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <!--app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"-->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:scrollbars="vertical" app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
        app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
        app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
        app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:itemCount="100"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**line.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**line_drawable.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line" />
</selector>
```

**thumb.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="44dp" android:topLeftRadius="44dp" android:topRightRadius="44dp" />
    <padding
        android:paddingLeft="22dp" android:paddingRight="22dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</shape>
```

**thumb_drawable.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb" />
</selector>
```

### The questions

1. Why does it occur?
   It worked fine for various other places...
2. How can I make the RecyclerView avoid both these cases, yet allow the navigation bar at the bottom show content of the RecyclerView as it is transparent?
3. In which cases should I add the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`? What does it do to help in these cases?

---

EDIT: a possible workaround is to avoid using CoordinatorLayout. It works well, but I wanted to do things "the official way". Here's this workaround:

Instead of CoordinatorLayout I used :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

...

And in code, I've set both margins and padding to the RecyclerView:

```
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(recyclerView) { _, insets ->
        val systemWindowInsets = insets.systemWindowInsets
        recyclerView.updatePadding(
            bottom = systemWindowInsets.bottom
        )
        recyclerView.updateMargins(
            left = systemWindowInsets.left,
            right = systemWindowInsets.right
        )
        insets
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As there is a comment discussion on my previous answer, I will not edit that one (it might also benefit someone).

The simplest thing to do, is to let the `AppBarLayout` handle the top and bottom insets. We can do this by using the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the `AppBarLayout`. For the items to be seen through the navigation bar, use `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the `RecyclerView`. Use `android:scrollbars="none"` on the `RecyclerView` to disable the normal scrollbar. The layout XML is then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
        app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
        app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
        app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the activity/fragment, we still have to handle bottom system inset for the `RecyclerView` and left and right system inset for both the `RecyclerView` and `AppBarLayout. We use margins for the`RecyclerView` to get the fast scroller into the content area.

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(recyclerView) { _, insets ->
            val systemWindowInsets = insets.systemWindowInsets
            appBarLayout.updatePadding(left = systemWindowInsets.left, right = systemWindowInsets.right)
            recyclerView.updatePadding(bottom = systemWindowInsets.bottom)
            recyclerView.updateMargins(left = systemWindowInsets.left, right = systemWindowInsets.right)
            insets
        }
```

Video result [here, comment #27](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143530492#comment27).

Comment: Nice. Thank you! This is much less of a workaround like the other person has offered :)

Comment: @40 I actually have found an issue on your solution. It's also shown on the video (here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143530492#comment27 ) . When you scroll to the bottom, the thumb goes to be behind the nav-bar. It can't be touched there. I'm un-accepting this answer, but putting +1 for it.

Comment: Yep, because it ignores padding as we discussed. You can either wait for an official better implementation, use the FastScroller from my other answer here or implement your own. It depends on how much you need this functionality.

Comment: So you agree that this is a bug? I should post about this on the issue tracker, right?

Comment: It is already posted. I am the person from the issue tracker you have been talking to.

Comment: OK I reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143972309

Comment: I have told you that it's already opened: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143786834

Comment: You have? Where? And how can you understand anything from such a short text and without sample/video/screenshot ? How did you find this?

Comment: Did you open this issue? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143530492. If you did, check comment #16. The person from Google has opened the issue for you.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. Still, the text there don't help at all to understand the issue.

Comment: That's what the "Blocked by" and "Blocking" at the top of the issue are for.

Comment: I don't know what this means.

Comment: I've decided to give you +1 for the other solution too, as it seems it works fine as a workaround for this issue.

Comment: Say, do you know how to solve a similar issue for ActionMode? For some reason I can't find a way to adjust it, so I reported about this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145055235

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note, you likely have set `android:clipToPadding=false"` on the RecyclerView although it is not visible above (otherwise the items would not be fully visible behind the navigation bar).

## First part

The first part (bottom padding in portrait mode) is very easy to solve. It seems that the CoordinatorLayout somehow moves the RecyclerView down by the top inset (very likely caused by ScrollingViewBehavior, did not research much further). So the solution is to add both the bottom and the top inset to the bottom padding of the recycler:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(recyclerView) { _, insets -> 
    val systemWindowInsets = insets.systemWindowInsets
    recyclerView.updatePadding(
        left = systemWindowInsets.left,
        // Fix CoordinatorLayout behavior
        bottom = systemWindowInsets.bottom + systemWindowInsets.top
        right = systemWindowInsets.right
    )
    insets
}
```

## Second part explanation

The second part is a bit more tricky. The easier part is the double scrollbars, but then comes the fast scroll behind the navigation bar. The padding is *part* of the view (check the layout inspector in Android Studio, you will see the RecyclerView extending all the way into the navigation bar). When the RecyclerView fast scroll implementation (which is based on ItemDecoration) displays the line and thumb, it does *not* account for padding.

The RecyclerView checks the `app:fastScrollEnabled="true"` attribute and calls `initFastScroller(...)` method, which creates a `FastScroller` object (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.java#11506)). However, you cannot extend this class, as it has a `@VisibleForTesting` annotation (annotation info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/VisibleForTesting), source code for `FastScroller` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/FastScroller.java)).

## Solution for the second part

#### Double scrollbars fix

The easy thing to solve is the double scrollbars. You have to disable the normal scrollbars and show only the fast scroll ones. To do that, use `android:scrollbars="none"` on the RecyclerView instead of `android:scrollbars="vertical"`.

#### Fast scroll fix

For the fast scroller, what you can do, is copy the code from the `FastScroller` and change some things to account for padding. **Note**, that this will also change the portrait mode - the fast scrollbar  will extend only to the navigation bar. The final code for the so called `FastScroller2` is [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RgYD1GmP) (it's a bit long, so I won't paste it here). Just create a new Java class called `FastScroller2` and paste the code.

You can then use the `FastScroller2` like this (called from `onCreate`)

```
private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.adapter = ... // Your adapter here
    val thumbDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.thumb_drawable) as StateListDrawable?
    val lineDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_drawable)
    val thickness = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fastScrollThickness)
    val minRange = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fastScrollMinimumRange)
    val margin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fastScrollMargin)
    if (thumbDrawable != null && lineDrawable != null) {
        // No need to do anything else, the fast scroller will take care of 
        // "connecting" itself to the recycler view
        FastScroller2(recyclerView, thumbDrawable, lineDrawable,
            thumbDrawable, lineDrawable, thickness, minRange, margin, true)
    }
}
```

The thickness, minRange and margin dimensions were copied from the recycler view library, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/res/values/dimens.xml), added to dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="fastScrollThickness">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fastScrollMargin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fastScrollMinimumRange">50dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This also means you don't need any fast scroller code in the layout xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    tools:itemCount="100"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a solution. It's a set of workarounds that might not always work and only adjusts itself to the issue. You just add more space. If this is a bug, they should just fix it

Comment: It's not a bug as this is intended behavior. Padding IS PART of the view, so they draw it there. What you need is CUSTOM behavior, which the framework does NOT provide for you.

Comment: If you set margins, everything would work ok, as margins are NOT part of the view. But you want the items behind the navigation bar, so you have to use padding with clipToPadding set to false.

Comment: But I have set padding for the RecyclerView, and as I wrote it doesn't work well. I add the bottom inset because that's what's important here. The RecyclerView is already below the toolbar, so that's what's supposed to be missing. Besides, the issue is also on the sides, as the RecyclerView draws content on the navigation bar there too, and ignores the padding I set to there. Why would I need a special behavior? Why can't the original one work? How come it isn't mentioned on the docs about this special case? There are RecyclerView everywhere... I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Even you wrote that "CoordinatorLayout somehow moves the RecyclerView down by the top inset " , which means the top is already handled. And visually you can also see it : the RecyclerView is set nicely at the top, so the top is already handled and shouldn't affect anything else.

Comment: Yes, something weird is going on with CoordinatorLayout and AppBarScrolling behavior. But if you really need CoordinatorLayout, the solution works okay.

Comment: About the RecyclerView, I see now that the normal scrollbar behaves correctly. It is just a missing implementation on their end. What you can do now is wait for them to support this use case or write your own solution, be it a modified FastScroller or your 100% custom solution.

Comment: What I see in this solution is different from what you describe. Can you please post it to Github so I can check it there? Maybe I'm missing here something, because no matter what I try, I always see a different issue that's missing handling. Also, I still consider it all a set of workarounds instead of having it simple. I don't believe Android development should be this annoying, at least not here.

Comment: I've noticed an issue: On some cases,I would like to add padding to the bottom of the RecyclerView (example: `android:paddingBottom="128dp"` for the RecyclerView),to have some space for FAB that is shown on top,so that it won't interfere with the item at the bottom.Using this solution is problematic,because the fastScroll will either include the part of the transparent navigation bar,or be much smaller as it will use the padding in addition to the navigation bar (`considerPadding`=true).Any suggestion?Here's a link: https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll/issues/34#issuecomment-763206834

Comment: I just took a quick 5 minute look, but don't see the whole picture. Are you still using window insets and calling `updatePadding`? How do you add bottom padding, because `updatePadding` would overwrite it?

Comment: In some places in the app I don't need to handle the insets. But I do want to have the ability to have padding to the RecyclerView itself (in the layout XML file), to offer space for FAB to be shown on top without hiding the last items. In the sample I've provided, I don't use insets at all. Do you think I did it wrong?

Comment: I think it's partially because of clipping. I think that if I disable clipping, there are no issues, but then I can't use the padding trick, and I would have to use something else instead (like margin for the last item, for example).

Comment: I don't think XML only is going to work. I think a better ReyclerView solution is to use custom ItemDecoration, that adds a predefined bottom offset to only the last item. An example of this (it's called padding, even though this is more like a margin) can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/vincetreur/4623110107c07c44b390 (this one also adds some top margin). It is likely something you need, because margin will not affect the calculations for `considerPadding = true`

Comment: This will however likely make the item non-clickable in the margin region (where the FAB is). If that's an issue, I can also propose another solution.

Comment: Why would it be a problem that the user presses an empty space (the margin area) ? The FAB is what's important there. Pressing empty space shouldn't do anything... Anyway, I've found this solution for adding spacing at the end, but as I've tried them, I noticed that each has issues, so I wrote it (based on something I've found) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858514/878126 . Another possible good solution is using a view at the bottom, BTW, which will take the whole row. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad you were able to find a solution.