# clipToPadding(false) not working for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I try to make top padding that not appear when scrolling. I use that [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288167/add-margin-above-top-listview-item-and-below-last-in-android)
But it does not work.

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lvSavedList"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bNewList" />
```

But some place bitween listview and ActionBar remains.
What do i do wrong?
(test on android 2.3.3 samsung gio) 
Now my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lvSavedList"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screen]

Comment: you dont want top padding space ?

Comment: yes, i do not want it when i scrolling list

Comment: You'll laugh, but it's true. Bug in my device. I started emulator and all work awersome.

Answer (score 1):

An example of how i do this :

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/some_header_another_view"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@color/clr_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >
    </ListView>
```

Dimensions :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- margins -->
    <dimen name="margin_line">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_small">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_medium">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_large">16dp</dimen>

/resources>
```

Color :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <!-- Colors -->
   <color name="clr_divider">#CC333434</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: I see only two new base lines android:overScrollMode="never" android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay", but it does't help =(

Comment: What container are you using for the ListView ?

Comment: Maybe try using "
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"" (this white space may be a glitch)Can you add the entire layout in the question ?

Comment: And when you scroll the padding remain (at top) ?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! It's problem.

Comment: Well it should not x)  Some advices : Don't use orientation with relativelayout (it is relative), try removing the background of the relative layout, try a linear layout instead

Comment: I edit layout. Nothing changed. It seems like clipToPadding just not workin. May be trying on other device.

Comment: You'll laugh, but it's true. Bug in my device. I started emulator and all work awersome.