# cardview size not decreasing in my recycler view in my app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am very new to Android.  I am trying to resize my `cardview` but it has no effect and reverts to its previous size.  Can any one help me ?

Here is my `cardview` and `Recyclerview` code.

Recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_primary" tools:context=".Primary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

cardview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/row_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/row_image"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/row_title"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize full `CardView` i think you need to change these lines:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Nowadays, you only changed height of the image:

```
    android:layout_height="250dp"
```

Read also this: [What's the difference between fill_parent and wrap_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432763/whats-the-difference-between-fill-parent-and-wrap-content)

EDIT: Delete paddings in RecyclerView - the take some space.

If have more question, please free to ask

Comment: i want to display my card item without space in left and right side@piotrek1543

Comment: did you noticed paddings in recyclerView? delete them to have full width and height

Comment: i deleted both but again i am getting space in left side and right side @piotrek1543

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695581/cliptopaddingfalse-not-working-for-listview