# couldn't get custom listview with margin to work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

This is probably something simple, but I couldn't get it right. I am using a custom list fragment and I am trying to add some margin to it. Here's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_courner" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewProductName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewProductPic"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewProductName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/counter_bg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewProductPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewProductPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the outcome is [image: the outcome]

Now I would like to add margins on the top right bottom left. So the borders aren't so stick to the sides and to each other. I've try doing this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_courner" >
```

But it doesn't work. Here's the outcome:[image]

Does anyone has any idea to achieve the margin in my case? 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps your ImageView `layout_(width|height)` dimensions are the culprit. Set it to `wrap_content` and its `scaleType` attribute to `FIT_XY`

Comment: Change your width of Relative Layout to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using placing a divider in the ListView xml layout?

Also this question might be useful:
[Spacing between listView Items Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984313/spacing-between-listview-items-android)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. The problem is I am using a listFragment And I attach to activity programmatically. There's no such tag <listView in any of my layout

Answer (score 0):

OK I figure it out. Just in case anyone that looking for the same solution.

In my ListFragment

```
 @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(productListAdapter);
    //this is necessary to avoid unwanted gap colors 
    getListView().setDivider(null); 
    getListView().setDividerHeight(30);
    getListView().setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);
    getListView().setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
  }
```