# Add space between each item layout in inflate layout android

Tags: android, layout, spacing, android-inflate

I do inflate layout. I want give spacing between each item in layout. Like the image below

[image: Left side what i want to do, the right what i do]

This is my main code in xml. The parent layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#F2F2F2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp"/>
```

This is my inflate layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="3dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@color/white_pure">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blueTransfer"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can i do to get like image (left side). Have spacing between each item in inflate layout. Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Use margin instead of padding. Then, set background white and grey for each section.

Comment: How ? i think i already put margin for each layout. huhuu

Comment: can you provide fully each item view xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One soluion is change you item layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaa"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="bbbbbbbbbb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="Details"
            android:textColor="#00f"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Another solution is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaa"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="bbbbbbbbbb"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textColor="#00f"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then if you use `ListView`, you can increase spacing between `ListView` items by using `android:divider` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309871/5381331

Or for `RecyclerView`: [How to add dividers and spaces between items in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview)

Comment: @user7345006 you also can check the solution 2 ;)

Comment: but this one android:gravity="right|center" i can't use .. got error .. how to make word Details be in center and right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white_pure"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_details"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="9sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/blueTransfer" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the space (Margin) between two inflated layouts by java code like below, It works for me.

```
View v =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item,null);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Hope This will helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@color/white_pure">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order Attempt 1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="DETAILS"
        android:textColor="@color/blueTransfer"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="#F2F2F2" />
```

I also just think this trick .. put view .. it also worked .. Thank you all for helped me .. :-)

Answer (score 0):

just use pading instead of marging in item's top group.and listview use margingLeft and margingRight.item code like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:background="@color/white_pure">
```