# How to remove item padding in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I recently create a listview with an array adapter and customview. here is what I do

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Model_order m_order = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_order, parent, false);
        }
...
}
```

and here is my `single_item_order`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/code"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"

    />

<TextView
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"

        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:textAlignment="center"
         />

    <TextView

    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is what I get

[image]

Now, I am trying to remove padding. here is what I try so far

- Add padding 0dp in my `single_item_order` still not working
- adding  `android:dividerHeight="0dp"` to my listview tag still not working
- trying this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309871/10298089 still
  no help

so how can I remove it ? or at least I can adjust the padding .

Here is my activity main which is containing my listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/bubble_outerWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            />
        <View

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/side_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Order Information"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                        <ListView
                            android:layout_below="@id/side_title"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:id="@+id/listss"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="250dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/listss"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <Button
                            android:minHeight="0dp"
                            android:minWidth="0dp"
                            android:id="@+id/clear"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="X"
                            />

                        <Button

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Pay"
                            />

    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try changing paddingBottom and paddingTop of your Linear Layout

Comment: How did you get white background for the item ?, add listview layout too

Comment: @MyNameIs Check my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler layout would look like this :

- A vertical `LinearLayout` to contain the `ListView` and the action bar
- The `LinearLayout` used for the action bar has its height to `wrap_content` so it only gets the height required by its children
- The `ListView` has its `height` to `0dp` and its `weight` to `1` in order to let it take all the available space left by the action bar

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <LinearLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:drawingCacheQuality="high">
>     <ListView
>         android:id="@+id/messagingListView"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:divider="@null"
>         android:layout_margin="0dp"
>         android:dividerHeight="10dp"
>         android:paddingTop="10dp"
>         android:paddingRight="10dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="0dp"
>         android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:padding="0dp"
>         android:background="#FFFFFF">
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/button"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="new_game"
>             android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

If space remains, you should definitly show us the layout used for list items

Note :
In Android Studio, try to single click on the `LinearLayout` to let it be highlighted in the `Preview`, then on the `ListView` to see if there is a gap (Use the zoom).
If you see a gap with the layout just above, it's an `Android Studio Preview` bug on your computer, it works on every devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"-->
    <!--android:visibility="visible"-->
    <!--android:textAlignment="center"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_weight="0"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="asdfa"-->
    <!--android:includeFontPadding="false"-->
    <!--android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"-->

    <!--/>-->

<TextView
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/qty"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />

<TextView

    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/min"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp" />
```